# Access request object from class based view

Tags: python, django

I have code like below

```
url(r'login$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

and view as follows

```
class LoginView(TemplateView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #How to operate on request Object's type and its params.
```

I have mentioned my question as comment in code.

Comment: `self.request` gives you the `request` object. You can aceess the objects like you would normally do.. `self.request.user`, etc.. ?

Comment: @karthikr When I try to do the same I getting error `'LoginView' object has no attribute 'request'` error.

Comment: hang on.. why are you overriding `__init__` ? you should be doing the processing in `get_context_data`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @karthikr you shouldn't be overriding `__init__()`. The request object is first available in the `dispatch()` method, which is called immediately after `__init__()`, but you shouldn't need to override that method either. Its primary purpose is to call the `get()`, `post()`, or other relevant method handlers. Generally speaking, however, it's not necessary to override those either.

If you really absolutely must catch the request at the earliest point possible though, then the dispatch method is your best bet.

```py
class LoginView(TemplateView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print self.request  # Works!
        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)  # Don't forget this
```

Comment: Can I name method like `def any_method_name(self, request, *args, **kwargs):` (not `def dispatch(...` ?

Comment: @AlexeiMarinichenko No; for this use case, you have to use the name `dispatch`.

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm Not for this case, but I need to override `__init__()` for initializing some variables. Please guide what's the drawback of overriding `init`? Note, I'll also be calling `super().__init__(kwargs)` while overriding.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to initialize variables, the best place is the setup function:

```
class SomeBaseView(View):
    var1 = None

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # do the vars initialization here
        self.var1 = kwargs.get('param')  # e.g.
```

By the way, setup function is called before dispatch and you dont need to return anything unlike dispatch.

> When the view is called during the request/response cycle, the setup() method assigns the HttpRequest to the view’s request attribute, and any positional and/or keyword arguments captured from the URL pattern to the args and kwargs attributes, respectively. Then dispatch() is called.
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view

Using dispatch function on the other hand is NOT recommended since you need to return the super call which can make things complicated.